# Make existing classes implement traits in scala

Tags: scala, traits, mixins

I have a class that takes key value pairs, this can come in the form a of a map object or a case class for example. Lets define the following abstraction:

```
 trait Reportable {
    def getAttributes : Map[String,Any]
  }
```

I want to have a method that takes a List[Reportable].
The possible implementations for reportable are:

- A map the implementation would just be itself
- A case class I could use something that uses reflection to take the attributes from a case class and put it into a map

The issue is i cannot figure out how to make Product (the base class of of all case classes) and the Map class implement my trait. I want to be able to take an existing class and mix in a the reportable trait, implementing it in terms of the methods the class already has.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot mix a trait in like that, I think.

However, imho, sounds like a case for the *EnrichMyLibrary* Pattern. Example for `Map`:

```
trait Reportable {
  def getAttributes : Map[String,Any]
}

object Reportable {
  implicit class MapReportableOps(private val underlying: Map[String, Any]) extends Reportable {
    def getAttributes: Map[String, Any] = underlying
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val reportables: List[Reportable] = Map("foo" -> "bar") :: Nil
```

The compiler should find the implicit wrapper class `MapReportableOps` for the map wherever a `Reportable` is expected and create a `Reportable`.

Comment: I get an error when i try that, illegal inheritance; superclass AnyVal
 is not a subclass of the superclass Object
 of the mixin trait Reportable
    implicit class MapReportableOps(private val underlying: Map[String, Any]) extends AnyVal with Reportable { . I am on scala 2.11

Comment: Just remove `extends AnyVal`.